# How to express that the text field is empty?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to do my own program for answering the questions via yes and no. But I have still one thread and I do not know what to do with it. I tried to express that my UIView (textfield) is not empty but xcode do not like the way I have done that. I am beginner so maybe there are more mistakes. I would appreciate every help :)

```
- (IBAction)generateAnswer:(UIButton *)sender {
if (_typeQuestion != nil) {
    _showAnswer.text = _answer;
}
```

}

Comment: what is _typeQuestion?

Comment: _typeQuestion is my text field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if typeQuestion is not empty, and _typeQuestion is an UITextfield, then just use:

```
if ([_typeQuestion.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
     //It was empty
}
else {
    //It wasn't.
}
```

Note: `isEqualToString` compares two NSStrings. In order to get the NSString from the text field, you must use `.text`. Therfore -> `_typeQuestion.text`

Comment: The same problem as it was at another answer:No visible @interface for 'UITextField' eclares the selector 'isEqualToString'.

Comment: Okay, you got it. Yeah, isEqualToString only compares NSString.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if `_typeQuestion` is your text field or not but usually to see if it is empty you would use the operation `isEqualToString` and compare it to the empty string `@""`

So to see whether the text field is not empty you would use:

```
if (![_typeQuestion.text isEqualToString:@""])
```

Comment: well, I do not know why but now it tells me:No visible @interface for 'UITextField' eclares the selector 'isEqualToString'. I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: Are you using the isEqualToString on the text field itself or the text property inside the text field? isEqualToString will complain that it doesn't apply to UITextFields, it only compares Strings.

Comment: I used it for textfield itself, so I have to do a text property and then compare them?

Comment: Yes, isEqualToString will only compare two strings, not a UITextField and a String. So get the value of your UITextField by using [_typeQuestion text] or _typeQuestion.text